# How manage relationship on both sides multiple List collections with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Stack java 11 springboot 2.7
I can't, created an entity schema with mutiple relationships.
I have several errors, I can't get out of it I don't, what is the best error?

The user entity should save only this data as to the backup

The Address entity should save only this data and cascade over delegations as to saving and the reference id never changes.

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(...)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Builder
public class AdressMSSEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "...")
    private String adress;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "...")
    private UserEntity useEntity;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "adress", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<DelegueEntity> delegueEntities;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "adressDelegue")
    private List<DelegueEntity> delegationRecues;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "...")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DelegueEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "...")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "...")
    private AdressEntity adress;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "...")
    private AdressEntity adressDelegue;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(...)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Builder
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "...")
    private String idTech;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH})
    private List<AdressEntity> listAdressEntity;

}




@Repository
@Transactional
@PersistenceContext
public interface IAdressRepositoryJpa extends JpaRepository<AdressEntity, String> {
    Page<AdressEntity> findByAdressContaining(String adress, Pageable pageable);

    Page<AdressEntity> findByUserEntityIdTechContaining(String idTech, Pageable pageable);

    Page<AdressEntity> findByUserEntityContainingAndAdressContaining(String adress, String idTech,
                                                                                     Pageable pageable);

    @Query("select distinct a  from AdressEntity a left join DelegueEntity d.adress where a.adress "
            + "= :adress.adress")
    List<AdressEntity> findAllDelegueEntitiesAdressByAdressEntity(
            @Param("adress") AdressEntity adress);

    @Query("select distinct a  from AdressEntity a left join DelegueEntity d.adressDelegue = :adress.adress")
    List<AdressEntity> findAllDelegationsRecuesAdressDelegueByAdressEntity(
            @Param("adress") AdressEntity adress);

    @Query("select distinct a  from AdressEntity a left join UserEntity i.idTech = :adress.adress")
    List<AdressEntity> findAllUserEntityIdTechByAdressEntity(
            @Param("adress") AdressEntity adress);

}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlserverEntityManager' defined in class path resource [.../PersistenceSqlserverAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [....UserEntity.listAdressEntity, ....AdressEntity.delegationRecues]
```

Answer (score 0):

To have two way relationship between two entities with lists you need to use `@ManyToMany` annotation. Here is a good article that explains how to do it: [Many-To-Many Relationship in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many)

Comment: I don't need a many to many relationship I don't need a relationship n..n